# Parsing JSON array values

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

I faced with the problem while trying parse JSON array and list all values it has, I have the following JSON format

```
{
  "sdd": {
        "token":"1",
        "details":[{
              "type":"SOME_TYPE",
              "l":,
              "expiration_date":"12\/2020",
              "default":true,
              "expired":false,
              "token":"1"
         }]
   }
 }
```

JSON output I have

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("ssd");
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + jobj.getString("token"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + jobj.getString("details"));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

and in the log cat I getting org.json.JSONException: No value for ssd this output

Comment: its not a valid json. Please update your right Json.

Comment: your json file is error(line 6), check him !

Comment: You could use gson to automatically parse json data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo. Not `ssd` but `sdd`. And also `sdd` is not array, but object. 
So you must write like:

```
JSONObject jb = response.getJSONObject("sdd");
```

Full parsing code will be like:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject sdd = response.getJSONObject("sdd");
        JSONArray details = sdd.getJSONArray("details");
        for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj = details.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e(TAG, "response-type:" + jobj.getString("type"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response-token:" + jobj.getString("token"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response-expiration_date:" + jobj.getString("expiration_date"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response-default:" + jobj.getBoolean("default"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response-expired:" + jobj.getBoolean("expired"));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Also, let me suggest you to use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) this library will help you deserialize your json representations.

Comment: hold on let me try it

Comment: @Stakerrrr if you solve your problem with my answer, you must mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

ssd is an object.
You can get the array as follows:

```
JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject("sdd");
JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("details");
```

Comment: Note also that the JSON you are trying to parse is not valid.

Comment: Before you had "no value for ssd" and now "no value for token". Right? Try to fix the JSON and update the request, please.

Answer (score -1):

hi you must json file isn't create 
is create :

> {   "sdd":{
>       "token":"1",
>       "details":[
>         {
>           "type":"SOME_TYPE",
>           "expiration_date":"12/2020",
>           "default":true,
>           "expired":false,
>           "token":"1"
>         }
>       ]   } }

after you can get data from code :

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject ssd = response.getJSONObject("ssd");
        JSONArray details = ssd.getJSONArray("details");
        for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = details.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + obj.getString("type"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + obj.getString("expiration_date"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + obj.getBoolean("default"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + obj.getBoolean("expired"));
            Log.e(TAG, "response" + obj.getString("details"));

        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: there is typo, it will gave same error, in json representation wroted `sdd` but in code wroted like `ssd`

Comment: @AxborAxrorov my mistake sorry, I can tick your answer as correct if you want

Comment: @Stakerrrr oh ! is so bad , you first test my code and solved your problem ,So the best answer is my answer . please tick my answer thanks.